# Is there a WaitOne method that essentially calls Reset first?

Tags: c#, events, waithandle, autoresetevent

I'm using an AutoResetEvent where multiple Set calls can be made on an event (Exception handling).  There are times when an extra Set is called, thus when the code makes a second call on a WaitOne event, it just passes right through because the gate has already been opened.

The solution is to call Reset right before the WaitOne.  Is there a cleaner solution or is this the only way to do it?  Example code:

```
private void DoSomeWork()
{
    Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomeOtherStuff));
    thrd.Start();

    //mEvt.Reset();
    mEvt.WaitOne();

    //continue with other stuff
}

private void DoSomeOtherStuff()
{
    /* lots of stuff */

    mEvt.Set();
}

private void ExceptionTriggerNeedsToBreakOutOfDoSomeWork()
{
   mEvt.Set();
}
```

After the exception is handled, I need to call DoSomeWork again, but since Set may have been called in multiple exceptions (or rethrown exceptions), the WaitOne just flows through.

My solution is to always call Reset before the WaitOne.  Is this the approriate solution, poor design, or is there a different type of event that will handle this scenario?

EDIT: I just moved the commented Reset (proposed solution) next to the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My concern would be that if you call Reset() before WaitOne(), you're in trouble if no Set() is ever called.  This might happen if you call Set(), then hit Reset() immediately afterwards, before hitting WaitOne().  Even if you're calling Set() twice, there's no guarantee you won't call Reset() after both, blocking the thread with no mechanism for release.

Ideally, you would have a try..catch..finally block, and call the Set() in the finally block, and not have your exception handling spread across methods.  Does that work for you?

Hans is correct that in this scenario, the multithreading is unnecessary.  My concerns only apply if you are truly multithreading with your calls to WaitOne().

It also concerns me that you're calling set more than once... does that mean that when the first set is called, the resource should really remain locked?  If you're still able to hit Set() a second time, to me that says you're still executing code that works with shared resources.  In which case you don't want the call to WaitOne() to unblock.

Also note, from the MSDN:

> There is no guarantee that every call to the Set method will release a thread. If two calls are too close together, so that the second call occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released. It is as if the second call did not happen.

In any case, it seems like your code should either go the route of throwing an exception, or running to completion, but not both.  I.E. you shouldn't be calling Set() twice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Regardless if Reset is first or not there, I'm in trouble if no Set is ever called - the method will hang. This is why I call Set in my Exception handling. The try/catch/finally might work, I will have to test it. This isn't my exact scenario - I'm using the built in Async calls and using events to sometimes make one of them a sync method (MS code examples suggested this - not proof that its good code, but it seemed like a good solution).

Comment: However, if you call Set() and then hit WaitOne(), WaitOne() will not block and continue.  If you call Set(), then Reset(), then WaitOne(), you will block and never return.  Set() will leave the event signaled if no thread is currently waiting.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I want to happen!  DoSomeOtherStuff will call Set when its done.  If that method throws an exception, the Exception handler will call Set - the WaitOne get released either way, and will not hang.  However, if a re-thrown exception calls Set on that event, then the next time through, WaitOne will NOT wait like I'm hoping it will.

Comment: The simple example you've listed isn't likely to hang, but in the real code, it's very possible.  It happens like this:  (1) thrd.Start, (2) main thread continues (3) simultaneously, the new thread is executing, (4) the new thread completes and calls Set() before the main thread gets to WaitOne().  In this situation, if you call Reset() before WaitOne(), you've already missed the Set() signal, and there's no executing code left to call it again.  I will try to think more on what you're saying you do want to happen, still absorbing that.

Comment: Ahh, Ok.  Thank you!!  I see what you are saying - and now understand the reason the AutoResetEvent class was designed this way.  It may well be that the answer I'm looking for is "no, it doesn't exist".  The reason being that even with my WaitOne a single line away from my ThreadStart, the thread could still theoretically finish before the WaitOne is called - the problem you describe.  Thank you!  I'm guessing the solution I'm looking for doesn't exist, I'll have to figure out something else!!  Thanks again!!

Comment: NP :)  In the comments in Hans' answer, I gave some details on why I think you can't have the WaitOne() approach work with two Set()s, and how I'd handle the scenario (based on my limited understanding :)  Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 4):

This is not a real problem, the WaitOne() call automatically resets the event.  After all, you used an AutoResetEvent, not a ManualResetEvent.  Key phrase here is Auto Reset.

Seeing it steaming right through the WaitOne() call is pretty normal too.  You've got a nice multiple core CPU, the thread got started right away when you called Start() and didn't take but a few microseconds to get the job done.  Milliseconds, whatever, faster than the blink of your eye.

Perhaps more to the point, you just don't need a thread here.  Starting one, then waiting for it to finish is pointless.  Just call the DoSomeOtherStuff() directly.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it to steam right through WaitOne.  I want it to ALWAYS stop at WaitOne - even if Set had been called on the event before WaitOne.

Comment: What on Earth for?  If it is done then it is done.  Maybe it will make you feel better if you call Sleep(1000), now you can see it.

Comment: I understand Auto/Manual event differences.  This isn't my exact scenario - I don't have a choice on the "thread", I'm using built-in Async calls and using events to sometimes make one of them a sync method (MS code examples suggested this - not proof that its good code, but it seemed like a good solution).

Comment: But what does that mean, if you call Set() but aren't really done with the WaitHandle?  Set() is a signal to the waiting thread, it means "I'm done now, you can continue"

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what exactly you are waiting for it will help make it clear to us

Comment: I'm using the Async, BeginConnect and BeginRecieve.  I want to wait for the connection to complete before allowing another one.  If the Callback methods or other method in the class throws an exception I have a CloseConnection method that has to trigger these events so this and other methods can complete properly.  I have a specific case where exception handling will re-throw an exception and when caught again, then calls Set one more time because it isn't aware of the first call to Set.  This opens the WaitOne gate the next time through.

Comment: Regardless of my exact code (maybe mine is bad design - I have to figure that out still :-)), I think there is a good case for event handling that ALWAYS waits at a WaitOne blocking mechanism regardless of whether the gate has been set or not.  I'm trying to see if this type of class exists?

Comment: "I want to wait for the connection to complete".  Well, that's easy.  Call Connect(), not BeginConnect().  Why are you making this difficult?  There's a two-by-four aiming at your forehead here.

Comment: I don't think there can be any such class, because if you wait when a Set() has been called, there's no guarantee there's going to be another Set() call... once again, you'd block with nobody available to set you free.

Comment: I think the key to this is in your error-handling... I really think you need to find a way to do an either-or path with your Set()s... either you have an error handler that is triggered and calls Set(), or the code completes successfully, and you call Set().  You just can't do both and expect the waiting thread to know whether it will wait for only one or both Set()s to be called.